# Cant access asp labels properties using c# in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to access an asp label field properties from c# code, and it keeps giving me the error:

> The name 'lblTest' does not exist in the current context.

This is happening on my login.aspx page when calling the 'ValidateEmail' method.

There are no associated .cs files, just a login.master page.

I have a business request requiring me to modify someone elses code for enhancement, and I am guessing this has something to do with the existing content structure of .

I have tried placing this in master file, outside of the  structure, etc. Still no joy.

**Here is the login.aspx code:**

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Masters/Login.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Culture="auto" UICulture="auto" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Internal.Platform.Diagnostics" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Internal.Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Internal.Trial" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Internal.Web.Controls" Namespace="Internal.Web.Controls" TagPrefix="Internal" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Internal.Web.Controls" Namespace="Internal.Web.Controls.ScriptResourceProvider" TagPrefix="Internal" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Internal.Trial" Namespace="Internal.Trial" TagPrefix="InternalTrial" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderArea">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Login ID="intLogin" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="Default.aspx"
        OnPreRender="PreRender" Font-Names="Arial,Verdana,Sans-sarif" Font-Size="0.8em"
        ForeColor="#000000">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div id="logoContainer">
                <div class="logo"><img src="images/icons/logo.png" width="680" height="100"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="logonContainer">
                <div>
                    <div class="LoginBtn1" onclick="lgnUser('pam')">Admin - Pam</div>
                    <div class="User1"><img src="images/icons/user1.png" width="80" height="80"></div>
                    <div class="LoginBtn2" onclick="lgnUser('lee')">Sales - Lee</div>
                    <div class="User2"><img src="images/icons/user2.png" width="80" height="80"></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="LoginBtn1" onclick="lgnUser('samantha')">Support - Samantha</div>
                    <div class="User1"><img src="images/icons/user3.png" width="80" height="80"></div>
                    <div class="LoginBtn2" onclick="lgnUser('larry')">Marketing - Larry</div>
                    <div class="User2"><img src="images/icons/user4.png" width="80" height="80"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest"></asp:Label>

            <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                OnServerValidate="ValidateEmail" ValidationGroup="ValidateGp"
                ErrorMessage="This is a custom error validator" runat="server"/>

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="ValidateGp"/>

            <%-- These are hidden controls used for the login process --%>
            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" style="display: none;"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="UserNameRequired" ValidateEmptyText="True" OnServerValidate="ValidateUserName"
                    ClientValidationFunction="" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="<%$ resources: UserNameRequired %>"
                    ToolTip="<%$ resources: UserNameRequired %>" ValidationGroup="intLogin" Text="<%$ resources: asterisk %>"></asp:CustomValidator>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" style="display: none;"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" CommandName="Login" style="display: none;" ValidationGroup="intLogin" />
            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>

        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>    
</asp:Content>
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    private const string AuthError = "AuthError";

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        EnsureChildControls();
    }


    protected new void PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object msg = Internal.Platform.Application.ApplicationContext.Current.State[AuthError];
        if (msg == null)
        {
            var pageId = Internal.Platform.Application.ApplicationContext.Current.State["CurrentPageID"];
            var key = pageId + ":" + AuthError;
            msg = Internal.Platform.Application.ApplicationContext.Current.State[key];
        }
        if (msg != null)
        {
            Internal.Platform.Application.ApplicationContext.Current.State.Remove(AuthError);

            Literal FailureText = (Literal)intLogin.FindControl("FailureText");
            FailureText.Text = msg.ToString();
        }
    }

    private static void SetAuthError(string errorMsg)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMsg))
        {
            Internal.Platform.Application.ApplicationContext.Current.State[AuthError] = errorMsg;
        }
        else
        {
            Internal.Platform.Application.ApplicationContext.Current.State.Remove(AuthError);
        }
    }

    protected void ValidateUserName(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        var oValidator = (CustomValidator)source;

        if (oValidator == null)
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
            SetAuthError(GetLocalResourceObject("InvalidUserNameValidation").ToString());
            return;
        }

        char cBadChar;
        BusinessRuleHelper.InvalidUserNameReason reason;

        if (BusinessRuleHelper.IsValidUserNameValue(args.Value, out reason, out cBadChar))
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
            SetAuthError(null);
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = false;

            switch (reason)
            {
                case BusinessRuleHelper.InvalidUserNameReason.NullOrEmpty:
                case BusinessRuleHelper.InvalidUserNameReason.WhiteSpace:
                    oValidator.ErrorMessage = GetLocalResourceObject("UserNameRequired").ToString();
                    break;
                default:
                    oValidator.ErrorMessage = GetLocalResourceObject("intLoginResource1.FailureText").ToString();
                    break;
            }

            SetAuthError(oValidator.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }

    protected void ValidateEmail(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
    if (Internal.Trial.TrialLogin.VerifyEmail(args.Value.ToString()))
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblTest = FindControl("lblTest") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label;
        lblTest.Text = "Test";
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    }

    protected void Page_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userName = (TextBox)intLogin.Controls[0].FindControl("UserName");
        string usrnm = userName.Text;

        Exception err = Server.GetLastError();
        if (err is Internal.Platform.Application.ValidationException)
        {
            string errMsg = err.Message;
        }
    }

</script>
```

**Here is the login.master code:**

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<script runat="server">
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Internal.Platform.TimeZones tzs = new Internal.Platform.TimeZones();
        Internal.Platform.TimeZone tz = tzs.CurrentTimeZone;
        if (Request.Params["tz_info"] != null)
        {
            string[] tzinfo = Request.Params["tz_info"].Split(',');
            if (tzinfo.Length == 11)
            {
                tz = tzs.FindTimeZone(tzinfo[0], tzinfo[1], tzinfo[2], tzinfo[3], tzinfo[4], tzinfo[5], tzinfo[6], tzinfo[7], tzinfo[8], tzinfo[9], tzinfo[10]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            log.Warn("TimeZone: Unable to get timezone from client, using server timezone.");
        }

        Internal.Platform.Application.IContextService context = Internal.Platform.Application.ApplicationContext.Current.Services.Get<Internal.Platform.Application.IContextService>(true);
        context.SetContext("TimeZone", tz);
    }
    Page.Title = GetLocalResourceObject("LoginPageTitle").ToString();
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function internalCleanUrl(strUrl) {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("internalclient") > -1) {
           strUrl = strUrl;
        } else {
           strUrl = "internalClient" + "/" + strUrl;
        }
        return strUrl;
    };
</script>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head2" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Saleslogix</title>

    <link type="text/css" href="../css/internalBase.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="../css/BDLogin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color : #f1f1f1;
            background-image: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script pin="pin" type="text/javascript"> 
        var dojoConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: true,
            async: true,
            isDebug: false,
            locale: '<%= Global.Locale %>',
            paths: { 'Internal.: '../../../jscript/Internal. },
            deferredOnError: function (e) {
                if (dojo.config.isDebug) {
                }
            }
        };
    </script>
    <script pin="pin" type="text/javascript" src="javascript:internalCleanUrl("Libraries/dojo/dojo/dojo.js">)"</script>
</head>
<body>
    <script pin="pin" src="Libraries/jQuery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script pin="pin" src="jscript/BDLogin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script pin="pin" src="jscript/timezone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script pin="pin" src="jscript/Internal.platform/gears_init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server" method="post" >
        <div class="LoginArea" id="LoginContainer">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderArea" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you strip down the sample code, so that it contains only the relevant parts?

Comment: Why is it called ContentPlaceHolderArea_lblTest instead of just lblTest?

Comment: Lol, I went to trouble of adding all the code, because past posts people then ask, can you post all the code!

Comment: Sorry, I was trying something with the ContentPlaceHolderArea_lbltest, as that is how the control id renders the source when viewing the page in the browser. I have tried using just lblTest as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a login.designer.cs file try to regenerate it (delete and then click on project and chose 'convert to web application').

Comment: Thanks, but as the original post states there are no .cs files associated.  =/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/C#" runat="server">
        protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblTest = FindControl("lblTest") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label;
            lblTest.Text = "Test";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" OnClick="btnTest_Click" Text="test" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you gave me works fine standalone the way you presented it up there, and I had high hopes it would work once I injected the relevant pieces into my code, because it did not give any warnings or errors. Unfortunately when I run it, and it gets to the portion of the code where it finds label control and sets its value, it gives the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  I tried adding the label control in the base Login.aspx page, and the Login.masters page. I edited the code above to reflect the changes I made based on your code.

Comment: I'm convinced the null pointer exception is caused by something else, not the label, you can see a code I've uploaded - https://github.com/landeeyo/StackOverflow/tree/master/ASP.NET/Label%20access/LabelAccess - where I cut most of your logic. Try to debug the code and find what actually is NULL.